# Using bytefield with wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure, bytefield

I want to position a `bytefield` at the right side of the page. For that reason I use the `wrapfig` package. If I make the `wrapfigure` smaller than `0.8\textwidth` it doesn't work. If it's `0.8\textwidth` (or even wider) it looks crappy.

```
\newcommand{\messagestart}{\begin{wrapfigure}[p] \begin{centering} \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8} \\}
\newcommand{\messageend}[1]{\end{bytefield} \par\end{centering} \protect\caption{#1} \label{#1} \end{wrapfigure} }
```

I tried to reduce the `bitwidth`, but it still didn't go smaller than `0.8\textwidth`. Is it anyhow possible to make it at least `0.5\textwidth`?

Edit:
Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,naustrian,DIV=12,BCOR=1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Request}
    \messagestart
         \bitheader{0-7} \\

         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Type}
             \wordbox[tlr]{1}{0}
         \end{rightwordgroup} \\

         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Data}
             \wordbox[tblr]{4}{Data, 64 Bytes} 
         \end{rightwordgroup}

    \messageend{Request}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Note that `\centering` is a command. `centering` is not an environment. Perhaps you wanted the `center` environment. `bytefield` is not a standard environment (and I've no idea where you have it from). `wrapfigure` and `\gls` both require packages (they aren't standard either).

Comment: As requested, I added the example.

Comment: You should use `\newcommand{\messagestart}{\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth} \centering \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8} }
\newcommand{\messageend}[1]{\end{bytefield} \par \protect\caption{#1} \label{#1} \end{wrapfigure} }`.

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply, but that still does'nt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even try to reduce things like that for so many fine tunings (for example, number of lines for `wrapfigure` → `[11]` here) will be difficult to make.  Use `\centering` not `\begin{centering}` BTW.

This is how you should be using it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,naustrian,DIV=12,BCOR=1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Request}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8}
         \bitheader{0-7} \\

         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Type}
             \wordbox[tlr]{1}{0}
         \end{rightwordgroup} \\

         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Data}
             \wordbox[tblr]{4}{Data, 64 Bytes}
         \end{rightwordgroup}

    \end{bytefield}
    \par
    \caption{Request} \label{request}
    \end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is your version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=12,BCOR=1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\newcommand{\messagestart}[1][]{\begin{wrapfigure}[#1]{r}{0.5\textwidth} \centering \begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2em]{8}}
\newcommand{\messageend}[1]{\end{bytefield} \par \protect\caption{#1} \label{#1} \end{wrapfigure}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Request}
    \messagestart[11]
         \bitheader{0-7} \\

         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Type}
             \wordbox[tlr]{1}{0}
         \end{rightwordgroup} \\

         \begin{rightwordgroup}{Data}
             \wordbox[tblr]{4}{Data, 64 Bytes}
         \end{rightwordgroup}

    \messageend{Request}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Picture same as above.

Comment: Is'nt it possible to make a command for this? Because I need this very often. I tried to add the number of lines to the command, but it also fails. The funny thing is, that it doesn't even appear at the line, but very later in the document. But it has to be that command, because if I only use "figure" instead of "wrapfigure" it works perfectly.

Comment: @Nikolar Have you seen the lower part of my answer? You have to add a width to `wrapfigure`. Please read the first two pages of `wrapfig` manual (`texdoc wrapfig` from command prompt). The positition specifier `R` allows to float and `r` doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! Finally with the R it works. But it positions the bytefields not really at the place, where I want them to. :D
I guess, I'll have to invest a little bit of time, to get the result, which I want.

Comment: @Nikolar No `R` will make the figure to float, that means it can appear elsewhere. Better use `r` if you want it *here*.

Comment: I'm afraid, with `r` it does'nt work. Everytime I change it to `r`, it stops working.

Comment: @Nikolar Hmmm. Strange. It works for me.

Comment: I've placed the bytefield on another position and now it works. It seems like it can't be placed before a description list.

Comment: Btw how did you calculate the number of lines?

Comment: @Nikolar hehe, I counted `;-)`  Yes `wrapfigure` shouldn't be used in and around `list`s. Manual is very clear about it.