# Insert graphic and stretch to textwidth, textheight

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert a graphic and stretch it to textwidth and textheight. I get a overfull box and an empty page befor the graphic. But it works when I only strech in horizontal reps vertical direction. Why I can't stretch in both directions?

This works as I want

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

But this yields an overfull vbox and an empty page

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

The only difference is the `width=\textwidth`.

Comment: Anyway specifying both will distort your image.

Comment: It's a small distortion and it's necessary because the graphics will be printed in a large, given format and exhibited. It's not possible to change the inserted graphics so I have to stretch them. Anyway I wonder, why it doesn't work with includegraphics.

Comment: Fix: `\includegraphics[height=.9999\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}`.  Sounds like a roundoff issue.  Note that an extra `9`, that is `.99999`, breaks it again.

Comment: To avoid `overfull hbox` I also need `width=.9999\textwidth`. I also think, it's a roundoff issue because the log says `0.16693pt` to high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be one of roundoff.  Changing

```
\includegraphics[height=\textheight, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[height=.9999\textheight, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

fixes the problem, whereas an extra `9`,

```
\includegraphics[height=.99999\textheight, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

breaks it again.  Such roundoff issues should not be too surprising, if one considers that constraining both the height and width is not a pure scale, but will require several constrained length multiplications in order to determine the final aspect and dimensional scale.

This MWE demonstrates the issue:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newsavebox\tmpbox

\begin{document}
\the\textheight{} actual textheight

\savebox\tmpbox{\includegraphics[height=.9999\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\the\ht\tmpbox{} .9999 is below

\savebox\tmpbox{\includegraphics[height=.99999\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\the\ht\tmpbox{} .99999 is above

\savebox\tmpbox{\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\the\ht\tmpbox{} scaled to textheight is above
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: cf https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=graphics/4451

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for the pointer to what I knew had to be a known issue.

Comment: I encountered it there http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291839/arithmetic-overflow-error-using-bytefield-package-while-attempting-to-constrain/291860#291860 see the comments below my answer

Comment: It should be noted, however, that the rounding error is below the usual `\hfuzz`/`\vfuzz` threshold, even in a case like this, in which relatively large dimensions are involved.  So, the only issue is the first empty page, due to the well-known problem of the initial `\write-1{}` before the first `\topskip` glue.  In other words, what I am trying to say is that this is a rather exceptional example.